# Get Ip address form browser call inside a script

Tags: angularjs

It is possible to retrieve the ip address form browser with AngularJS?
If yes, could you give me an example?

Scenario: 
In browser I make the following call - http://someip:port/controller . 
I need the value of "someip" inside a script and I don't know how to do that...

Thanks!

Comment: How do you make this call, http request?

Comment: if its the server your website is being hosted you can just use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can get the ip,
but you can pretty much get everything else usin

```
window.location
```

Like

```
 window.location.host
 window.location.port
 window.location.hostname
```

etc